# Image upload to Imgur API via JS Fetch API is canceled by browser

Tags: javascript, fetch, imgur

I wrote [a small application on Codepen](https://codepen.io/raddevon/pen/JMgVVq) to upload to a specific Imgur album using Javascript's Fetch API. The application is failing to upload, and I'm not sure why since I'm not actually getting a response from the server. The browser appears to be canceling the request rather than sending it off.

[image: Chrome dev tools network tab request canceled]

[image: Chrome dev tools request details]

Here's my code:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const fileInput = event.target.querySelector('input');
  const imageFile = fileInput.files[0];

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', imageFile);
  formData.append('album', 'EVGILvAjGfArJFI');

  fetch('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: 'Client-ID 90ef1830bd083ba',
    }),
    body: formData
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      alert('Image uploaded to album');       
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    alert('Upload failed: ' + error);
  });
});
```

I'm not sure if I need to be reading the file or if I can pass the file object directly into the form data. I've seen examples of both methods online, and I've tried both with the same result. I notice dev tools doesn't seem to show the image data in the request body. Not sure if that means it isn't being sent or if Chrome is just not displaying it since it wouldn't be human-readable anyway. I've tried the request with CORS mode on and off.

Any guidance on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you need to also append the `init:{credentials: "include"}` option to your `fetch`?  It won't send cookies otherwise.

Comment: @zero298 It doesn't appear to need cookies. The only authentication needed for the request is the `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For FormData, you don't actually need the Content-Type header. The browser automatically adds that for you when have a FormData type in the body. I think that's because that header needs some additional info (when the browser automatically handles it, it looks like `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryvAmR7mCXOyHiPIH5` on my machine).

Here's the updated pen that looks like it's working:
https://codepen.io/ccnokes/pen/wyBYOd

Also, because you're submitting that data via a `<form>` but handling the request via `fetch`, you need to tell the `<form>` not to do a full page navigation change to POST the form (which cancels the fetch). So I added `event.preventDefault()` in the `submit` handler on that form.

Comment: This does work. Looks like the request still throws, but the request *does* get to Imgur and the image ends up in the album. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just tested it again and it doesn't throw for me. Weird. Well, glad it helped!

Comment: Just noticed one other change you made that is critical: `event.preventDefault()`. I think the event propagation causes my fetch request to be canceled by the form submission. Might want to add that to your answer as well.

Comment: @raddevon oh yeah, forgot about that. Updated it.